# How can I make a list or a dictionary with each element being a class instance?

Tags: python, oop

I don't think the design below is a good idea. However, this is for an exam, and they require a list (technically an array, because Cambridge is very biased in favour of VB and Pascal) where each element is of a certain class type. Here is the class diagram:

[image: Class diagram given by the exam board]

Also, the board demands that all attributes be private even though -- based on my rudimentary knowledge of Python -- "private" attributes aren't really a thing. Here is the code exhibiting the problem:

```
class Question():

    def __init__(self):

        self.__QuestionID = ""
        self.__QuestionText = ""
        self.__Answer = ""
        self.__Mark = ""
        self.__Topic = ""

class Test():

    def __init__(self):

        self.__TestdID = ""
        self.__Questions = [] 
        self.__NumOfQs = None
        self.__MaxMarks = 0
        self.__Level = None
        self.__DateSet = None


    def DesignTest(self):


        self.__NumOfQs = int(self.__NumOfQs)
        self.__Questions = [Question for x in range(self.__NumOfQs)] `        

        for i in self.__Questions:
            i = Question()              
            i.SetQuestion()
```

The last four lines are my problem area: I don't know how to implement the list of instance objects.

Comment: "Cambridge is very biased in favour of VB and Pascal" What? Surely you're not actually talking about [Cambridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Cambridge)?

Comment: @ArthurTacca Cambridge International Examinations for A levels and IGCSEs is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: Python doesn't have explicit private and public attributes.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in the final `for` loop: you already have a list, except that you filled it with the class object itself, instead of instances.  Try this:

```
self.__Questions = [Question() for x in range(self.__NumOfQs)]
```

Now you have a list of instance objects.  If you need to call `SetQuestion` on each, you already have it set up in that loop:

```
for i in self.__Questions:
    i.SetQuestion()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe I overlooked adding those two brackets.

Comment: Those are parentheses; brackets are the square ones that make a list.  Braces are the curly ones.  I can certainly believe it, since I still make that mistake about once a month.

Comment: Brackets, square brackets, curly brackets hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

You can just initiate them in the list itself.
use

self.__Questions = [Question() for x in range(self.__NumOfQs)]

then also try :

for i in self.__Questions:
    i.SetQuestion()

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
self.__Questions = [Question for x in range(self.__NumOfQs)]
```

will create a list with uninstanciated objects, as many as you have in `self.__NumOfQs`. If you want to create instanciated objects, just do

```
self.__Questions = [Question() for x in range(self.__NumOfQs)]
```

instead and skip the last lines, or skip the line above and do

```
for i in self.__NumOfQs:
    self.__Questions.append(Question())
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you just want a list containing instances of the `Question` class? You can simply instantiate them in the list generation.

```
self.__Questions = [Question() for x in range(self.__NumOfQs)]
```

You can then finish with:

```
for i in self.__Questions:             
    i.SetQuestion()
```